# Last day of selectected quarter

Tags: javascript, date

I am using the following function to find the last day of quarter of selected day. 
Now I am just adding 12*Date.WEEK but is not exactly what I want. 
Could you please have look and advice how to find the last day of quarter? I want to have the last day of quarter in date2.

```
 function catcalc(cal) { 
 var date = cal.date;
    var time = date.getTime(); 
    var field = document.getElementById("x_Bis");
    if (field == cal.params.inputField) {        
        field = document.getElementById("x_Von");
        time -= 12*Date.WEEK; // substract one week
    } else {                           
     time += 12*Date.WEEK; // add one week  6*Date.DAY
    }                                        
    var date2 = new Date(time);                              
  field.value = date2.print("%d.%m.%Y");
```

I should keep the function structure and keep the name of variable. There are two calendar fields which are linked to each others. The user can just select from calendar any date (no clock time is necessary). The function is coming from http://cimanet.uoc.edu/logica/v2/lib/jscalendar-1.0/doc/html/reference.html.

Comment: Why the calculation? if date < mar 31, last day = mar 31, else if < June 30, last day = june 30 and so on

Comment: You mean just check the date and put some if or switch? But how can store the last day to time?

Comment: I think my new code is more elegant now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding @mplungjan proposal (and minding the JavaScript dumbness when working with dates). I'll use method chaining, so every next method will operate on what previous method have returned.

```
function getLastDayOfQuarter(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var quarterEndings = [[3, 31], [6, 30], [9, 30], [12, 31]];

  var toDateObj = function (dates) {
    return new Date(year, dates[0] - 1, dates[1]);
  };

  var isBeforeEndDate = function (endDate) {
    return endDate >= date;
  }

  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  return quarterEndings
    .map(toDateObj)
    .filter(isBeforeEndDate)[0];
}

getLastDayOfQuarter(new Date()).toDateString(); // "Mon Mar 31 2014"
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eZoliye/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @mplungjan Could you be more constructive? I would like to improve it.

Comment: Bug 1: => should be >=; 
Bug 2: getLastDayOfQuarter(new Date(2014,2,31,23,59)).toDateString(); // != "Mon Mar 31 2014"

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, now I get why `setHours()` is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Updated Aug 2022

Using the fact that the 0th day of the next month in JS is the last day of current month. Note that months start at 0 so month 3 is April and the 0th of April is March 31

```js
const getQ = date => {
  const t = new Date(date.getTime()), year = t.getFullYear() // copy
  t.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // normalise before using
  return [3, 6, 9, 12].map(month => new Date(year, month, 0)).find(q=>t<=q)
};


// testing
const output = document.getElementById("output");
let d, q, dates = [new Date(2022, 2, 31, 23, 59), new Date(2022, 4, 31, 23, 59), new Date(2022, 9, 31, 23, 59) ];
output.innerHTML = dates
  .map(d => `${getQ(d).toLocaleDateString()} the end of the quarter containing ${d.toLocaleDateString()}`)
  .join("<hr/>");
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

But actually is the [calculation from Balage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70853768/295783) the simplest so far.

Here in a function since he did not bother

```js
const getQ = date => {
  let quarter = Math.floor((date.getMonth() / 3)), startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), quarter * 3, 1);
  return [startDate, new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth() + 3, 0)]
};

const output = document.getElementById("output");
let d, q, dates = [new Date(2022, 2, 31, 23, 59), new Date(2022, 4, 31, 23, 59), new Date(2022, 9, 31, 23, 59) ];
output.innerHTML = dates
  .map(d => {
    q = getQ(d);
    return `${q[0].toLocaleDateString()} is the start and ${q[1].toLocaleDateString()} the end of the quarter containing ${d.toLocaleDateString()}`;
  })
  .join("<hr/>");
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

Old version

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8RU3r/)

```
function getQ(date) {
  var t=new Date(date.getTime()),year=t.getFullYear() // copy
  t.setHours(0,0,0,0); // normalise to not get boundary errors
  // note months start at 0 in  JS
  var q1 = new Date(year,2,31),
      q2 = new Date(year,5,30),
      q3 = new Date(year,8,30),
      q4 = new Date(year,11,31);
  if (t<=q1) return q1;
  if (t<=q2) return q2;
  if (t<=q3) return q3;
  if (t<=q4) return q4;
}
getQ(new Date()); // today will return 31st of March
```

In your code, I would guess you can use

```
function catcalc(cal) { 
  var date = cal.date;
  var field = document.getElementById("x_Bis");
  if (field == cal.params.inputField) {        
    field = document.getElementById("x_Von");
  }                                        
  var date2 = getQ(date);
  field.value = date2.print("%d.%m.%Y");  
}
```

Comment: +1 for the original idea, but what an ugly code is this! Beside of the rest, are `setHours()` and `getTime()` necessary?

Comment: The set hours is to normalise, the get time maybe not. Also remember the noob status of op before you use map and other stuff you might find more elegant

Comment: If you are referring to OP's low rep, it may not be the case (he may have decades of programming experience in another language or so). Even if it is, `map()` and `filter()` are common methods that every JS developer must know, the sooner, the better, imo.

Comment: I have not used them yet since they are not compatible with all the browsers I code for and I find they lower the readability of simple array manipulation a lot.

Comment: :(, fortunately I already forgot when I had to support IE 8, so I use `map/filter/some/every` on a daily basis.

Comment: Good for you. If I need them I will let you know :) Only one year ago I had to include IE6 so I am happy with IE8 as lowest denominator

Comment: @Pavlo I updated my code. Now more elegant than your old code ;)

Comment: But actually [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70853768/295783) is the simplest

Answer (score 2):

This may be simpler than other answers. Gives you first and last date of current quarter. Works with other arbitrary dates if you change the first line.

```js
let now = new Date();
let quarter = Math.floor((now.getMonth() / 3));
let startDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), quarter * 3, 1);
let endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth() + 3, 0);

console.log(startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: Very nice. Why not make it a snippet?